# biblatex-chicago, cmsdate=both with same origdate and date

Tags: biblatex

On the subject of the `date` field in the author-date style, the `biblatex-chicago` manual states on p. 87:

> If the original publication dates — in the origdate field — are the same, and the reprint dates different, you may prefer citations of the two works to read, e.g., (Author [1898a] 1952) and (Author [1898b] 1974), when they in fact read (Author [1898] 1952) and (Author [1898] 1974). These latter forms aren’t ambiguous, and even if the reprints themselves appeared in the same year then the alphabetical suffix would appear attached to the date — (Author [1898] 1974a) and (Author [1898] 1974b) — again avoiding ambiguity.
>
> The Manual doesn’t give clear instructions for how to cope with these situations, but biblatex-chicago-authordate provides help.

However I haven't been able to recreate the last example mentioned, i.e. when the cited works have the same `date` and `origdate`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@book{Mises1963-1,
    author={von Mises, Ludwig},
    title={Human Action},
    subtitle={A Treatise on Economics},
    date={2007},
    edition={4},
    origdate={1996},
    publisher={Liberty Fund},
    location={Indianapolis},
    volume={1},
    volumes={3},
    editor={Greaves, Bettina Bien},
    part={1--3},
    pubstate={reprint}}

@book{Mises1963-2,
    author={von Mises, Ludwig},
    title={Human Action},
    subtitle={A Treatise on Economics},
    date={2007},
    edition={4},
    origdate={1996},
    publisher={Liberty Fund},
    location={Indianapolis},
    volume={2},
    volumes={3},
    editor={Greaves, Bettina Bien},
    part={4},
    pubstate={reprint}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{Mises1963-1} and \cite{Mises1963-2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces dates with the alphabetical suffix attached to the `origdate`, rather than the `date`, i.e. (Author [1898a] 1974) and (Author [1898b] 1974).

In my case, it would be more suitable to have the `extrayear` appear next to `date` rather than the `origdate`---like in the aforementioned manual example---, because the original was published as a single volume, which the reprints separated. It therefore makes no sense to disambiguate between the `origdate`s.

Playing with `cmsdate` global and per entry options, as well as `switchdates`, I haven't been able to achieve desired results. I would appreciate an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: The documentation on p. 87 refers to `cmsdate` used in-entry, not used in the preamble where pp. 88-89 apply. When `cmsdate`  is used in the preamble `origyear` is given the preference over `year` for `labeldate` creation (an `extrayear` is only ever attached to `labeldate`), such that you will almost always end up with `[1996a] 2007`. You can prevent this by using `cmsdate` per entry, then you will however get `[1996] 2007` at first (a situation which can be remedied with a redefinition of whose knock-on effects I cannot say anything).

Comment: All in all, I would suggest you stay with the original behaviour because the decision to prefer one output over the other seems very ad hoc here (what if the original had been split over several instalments while the reprint was one solid volume?) and the surgical operation into the inner workings of CMS are probably risky. That said, if you insist on a solution I might post it, but I cannot guarantee that it works smoothly in all corner cases.

Comment: Well, if the reprints had merged several volumes into one it would have been more suited for a `bookinbook` or `mvbook` I suppose. You are however right that it is probably a very rare situation. I just thought that there might be a way to achieve this with a minimal tweaking since it is one of the examples specifically mentioned in the manual.

Comment: Hmm, that is tricky. I'm not sure what the ideal answer would be. But bear in mind that the "author-date" reference is thought of as a noun phrase, and its primary purpose is to facilitate finding the works in a reference list. So, as long as these noun phrases are unambiguously unique, the work can be found easily. Readers should then be able to sort out (1) how to find the work [= most important] and (2) what the unique publication history is.

Comment: I think the part of the documentation you refer to is a relict from when `cmsdate` was not encouraged in the preamble and has not kept up with the change of `labeldate`. If you choose to use `cmsdate` only on a per-entry basis (that is remove it from the options), then indeed the needed modification is only one `%` (but for this redefinition one has to copy the forty-odd lines around that as well).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @moewe. I think I'm going to keep it as-is. jon is right that in the end author-date citations are primarily about finding the work in the references.